# How to improve performance of CAST IIF EXISTS in large data sets

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I'm currently working on a project with a large dataset in Microsoft SQL Server:

```
    Table_A ±250k rows;
    Table_B ±1M rows;
    Table_C ±6M rows;
    Table_D ±10M rows;
```

Currently I run into performance issues to get data out of these tables with a Table Valued Function.

On average, my query runs for 1,5s, which is too slow as we need to run 4 of them to run a web page. It get's worse when the database is under heavy load by multiple users, then the speed can drop to 6 second, causing total load times of 25s or longer of a webpage which is too slow.

I checked the execution plan, and found out that 70% of calculation is going into the `CAST(IFF(EXISTS(...)))` part:

```
    WITH cte1 AS (
        SELECT B.ID, B.NAME, B.A_Id
        FROM Table_B
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT B.A_Id, MAX(B.ID) AS Max_ID
            FROM Table_B B
            GROUP BY B.A_Id
        ) Q ON Q.A_Id = B.A_ID AND Q.Max_ID = B.ID
    ),
    SELECT  
        A.Id,
        A.<columns>,
    
        IsBusy= CAST(IIF(       
        EXISTS(
            SELECT C.ID
            FROM Table_C C
            INNER JOIN Table_D D 
                ON D.ID = C.D_ID AND C.B_ID = cte1.ID
           WHERE D.FinishDate IS NULL 
        ) , 1, 0) AS BIT),

        IsError= CAST(IIF (     
        EXISTS(
            SELECT C.ID
            FROM Table_C C
            INNER JOIN Table_D D 
                ON D.ID = C.D_ID AND C.B_ID = cte1.ID
            WHERE D.FinishDate IS NOT NULL AND LEN(D.ErrorMessage) > 0
        ) , 1, 0) AS BIT)

    FROM Table_A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cte cte1 ON Table_A.Id = cte1.Id
    -- Other LEFT OUTER JOINS + WHERE statements are omitted for readability.
```

**My question:**
Why  is so much time wasted on this `CAST(IFF(EXISTS(..)))` construction? And what direction can I think of to improve performance?

I've never bumped really in such big tables that caused these kind of queries to perform bad.

Comment: Please show your full table definition, along with indexes, and please show your full query. Please also share your execution plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. We can't help you otheriwse, because tuning SQL is not a one-size-fits-all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to help without better info on your query, such as tables, indexes and a query plan.

But you can probably combine these two subqueries using conditional aggregation, inside an `OUTER APPLY` or a grouped `LEFT JOIN`.

You can also improve the CTE by using `ROW_NUMBER` or another window function.

```sql
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT
      B.ID,
      B.NAME,
      B.A_Id,
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B.A_Id ORDER BY B.ID DESC) AS rn
        FROM Table_B
    ) B
    WHERE B.rn = 1
)
SELECT  
  A.Id,
  A.<columns>,
    
  d.IsBusy,
  d.IsError
FROM Table_A a
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte cte1 ON a.Id = cte1.Id
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT
      ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN D.FinishDate IS NULL                                 THEN CAST(1 AS bit) END), 0) AS IsBusy,
      ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN D.FinishDate IS NOT NULL AND LEN(D.ErrorMessage) > 0 THEN CAST(1 AS bit) END), 0) AS IsError
    FROM Table_C C
    JOIN Table_D D 
      ON D.ID = C.D_ID
     AND C.B_ID = cte1.ID
) d

-- Other LEFT OUTER JOINS + WHERE statements are omitted for readability.
```

Or using a grouped `LEFT JOIN`

```sql
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      C.B_ID,
      ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN D.FinishDate IS NULL                                 THEN CAST(1 AS bit) END), 0) AS IsBusy,
      ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN D.FinishDate IS NOT NULL AND LEN(D.ErrorMessage) > 0 THEN CAST(1 AS bit) END), 0) AS IsError
    FROM Table_C C
    JOIN Table_D D 
      ON D.ID = C.D_ID
    GROUP BY
      C.B_ID
) d
  ON d.B_ID = cte1.ID
```

---

I would expect something like the following indexes

```sql
Table_A (ID) INCLUDE (otherColumnsHere)

Table_B (A_Id, ID DESC) INCLUDE (NAME)

Table_C (B_ID, D_ID)

Table_D (ID) INCLUDE (FinishDate, ErrorMessage)
```

Obviously these can be clustered indexes, especially if they are primary keys. In which case you don't need `INCLUDE`.